# How to make all possible combinations of a word in Python

Tags: python, string, list, replace, letter

I have a txt file with all of the letters in the alphabet that looks like this:

a

b

c

etc..

I also have a word list of words that is only 3 letters long:

ago

age

bat

bag

etc...

I want to create a list that prints out all of the combinations possible starting with the first word ago:

My test program looks like this:

```
allcombi=[]
s= list("ago")
the.list=[]
with open("alfabeth.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8") as letters:
    for line in letters:
        letter = line.strip()
        s[0]=letter
        print(s)
```

Now I only change the first letter, but I have a really hard time trying to join the letters because it only looks like this:

['a', 'g', 'o']
['b', 'g', 'o']
....

HELP WITH:

1. Print it out as  ['ago','bgo'] instead
2. Instead of just changing the first letter, change it one letter at a time in index 0,1 and 2 one letter at a time in the word. The output should be 27*3 rows long with ['ago','bgo',........,'agx',agy,'agz']

I will later search for all of the items in my new list in a dictionary but that I can figure out myself it's just this part that really gotten me stuck.

Comment: To join a string, use `join`. E.g. `''.join(['a', 'g', 'o'])` will output `"ago"`

Comment: Why do you need a text file with all of the letters in it?

Comment: Why wouldn't there be 26*3 rows?

Comment: `letter = line.striplines()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will generate a list of all combinations for a given word:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
word = "ago"
combos = []
for i in xrange(len(word)):
    for l in ascii_lowercase:
        combos.append( word[:i]+l+word[i+1:] )
```

Comment: To get the alphabet `from string import ascii_lowercase`

Comment: Thank you, this way way shorter than mine, and I didn't have to import a txt file with the alfabet

Answer (score 0):

as @Farhan.K put in the comments, what you are looking for is a string method that creates a new string from an iterable: `join`

Join is a method of a string where it joins an iterable containing strings with that original string in-between them. for example if you have a list of words that are to be a sentance, you can join them with a space separating each one by calling `' '.join(listOfWords)`. In your case, you have a list of chars that need to be joined without any delimiter, so you pass an empty string as the separator: `''.join(listOfChars)`

Answer (score 0):

here with list comprehension

```
[b+'g'+e for b in alphabet for e in alphabet]
```

and you can define alphabet with another list comprehension

```
alphabet=[chr(c) for c in range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)]
```

perhaps not much shorter than writing char by char...

Answer (score 0):

You need nested loops for starters. When you get the grip of what you actually trying to do, then you can see the itertools package.

With the code that you have provided, you should need something like:

```
s = list('ago')
the_list=[]
with open("alfabeth.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8") as letters:
    lines = [line for line in letters]

for i in range(len(s)):
    for ii in lines:
        tmp_s = list(s)
        tmp_s[i] = ii
        print(''.join(tmp_s))
```

And with itertools this becomes:

```
from itertools import product

s = list('ago')
with open("alfabeth.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8") as letters:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in letters]

for i in product(range(len(s)), lines):
    print(''.join(s[:i[0]] + [i[-1]] + s[i[0] + 1:]))
```

Comment: That seems to be an awfully convoluted way to get a list of the letters of the alphabet.

Comment: I think that the target is not to take all the letters of the alphabet. Please read again the OP.

Comment: "txt file with all of the letters in the alphabet"

Comment: Dude, please quote the whole sentence. "I I have a txt file with all of the letters in the alphabet". "I have"! He has that and wants something else. So, either you comment on my answer by mistake or you have to read again what the OP says.

Comment: No, he wants to do something else with it.  Maybe *you* should read the comments on the accepted answer...

Comment: OK...! I'll leave this here... it's an excerpt from the OP. "HELP WITH:  Print it out as ['ago','bgo'] instead  Instead of just changing the first letter, change it one letter at a time in index 0,1 and 2 one letter at a time in the word. The output should be 27*3 rows long with ['ago','bgo',........,'agx',agy,'agz']" (friendly hint: You could just admit that you are wrong)

Comment: I would if I was.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! With a neat while loop too. So proud. Posting answer here anyway.

```
    allakombi=[]
s= list("söt")#startord
characters=[]
with open("alfabetet.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8") as bokstäver:
        for rad in bokstäver:
               bokstav = rad.strip()
               characters.append(bokstav)

k=0
while k<3:
       i=0
       while i <len(characters):
              s= list("söt")
              s[k]=characters[i]
              i=i+1
              s="".join(s)
              allakombi.append(s)
       k=k+1


print(allakombi)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a few nested loops to get the combinations, as an example:

```python
from string import ascii_lowercase

words = ["ago"]
combs = []
for word in words:
    for i, letter in enumerate(word):
        for l in ascii_lowercase:
            tmp = list(word)
            tmp[i] = l
            combs.append("".join(tmp))

print combs



>>> ['ago', 'bgo', 'cgo', 'dgo', 'ego', 'fgo', 'ggo', 'hgo', 'igo', 'jgo', 'kgo', 'lgo', 'mgo', 'ngo', 'ogo', 'pgo', 'qgo', 'rgo', 'sgo', 'tgo', 'ugo', 'vgo', 'wgo', 'xgo', 'ygo', 'zgo', 'aao', 'abo', 'aco', 'ado', 'aeo', 'afo', 'ago', 'aho', 'aio', 'ajo', 'ako', 'alo', 'amo', 'ano', 'aoo', 'apo', 'aqo', 'aro', 'aso', 'ato', 'auo', 'avo', 'awo', 'axo', 'ayo', 'azo', 'aga', 'agb', 'agc', 'agd', 'age', 'agf', 'agg', 'agh', 'agi', 'agj', 'agk', 'agl', 'agm', 'agn', 'ago', 'agp', 'agq', 'agr', 'ags', 'agt', 'agu', 'agv', 'agw', 'agx', 'agy', 'agz']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like :

```
letter=["ago"]

from string import ascii_lowercase

for i in ascii_lowercase:
    print(i+letter[0][1:])
    print(letter[0][:1]+i+letter[0][2:])
    print(letter[0][:2]+i)
```